# How to check payment successfully?

Tags: 8, ubercart

I use module ubercart. Payment method is PayPal. I want process some task after user payment successfully. I write custom module. I want know how to check user payment successfully with some hook, event can catch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the answer with suggestion of maintainer module. I can use `hook_uc_payment_receipt_insert()` to do that.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_uc_payment_receipt_insert().
 */
function uc_payment_uc_payment_receipt_insert(PaymentReceiptInterface $payment) {
  $order = $payment->getOrder();

  // Log a message against the order.
  $method_name = $payment->getMethod() ? $payment->getMethod()->getPlugin()->cartReviewTitle() : t('Other');
  $log_message = t('@method payment for @amount entered.', array('@method' => $method_name, '@amount' => uc_currency_format($payment->getAmount())));
  $order->logChanges(array($log_message));

  // Automatically mark paid orders as "payment received".
  // @todo Remove when Rules is available.
  if (uc_payment_balance($order) <= 0) {
    $state = $order->getStateId();
    if ($state == 'in_checkout' || $state == 'post_checkout') {
      $order->setStatusId('payment_received')->save();
    }
  }
}
```

[Source](https://www.drupal.org/node/2849981)